# I want to update a table which has duplicate values column from unique value column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update a table where common column values are having duplicate but my source table common column does not having duplicate, its unique

[image]

Now I want to UPDATE TABLE_B set NAME from TABLE_A . how to do ?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: If you are learning Oracle, you should at least put your attempt in the question.

Comment: I am new to Oracle, I have attempted as much as possible i can

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query:

```
update table_b b set b.Name = (select a.Name from table_a a where b.ID = a.ID)
```

Comment: I have tried this , it resulted  ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: It means that this query returns more than one result for a specific Id. you need to be sure that you don't have a repeating id in table_a or you can just get the first result by changing it like this:  update table_b b set b.Name = (select max(a.Name) from table_a a where b.ID = a.ID)